Identification of nitrogen
I have read  that we identify  gases through chemical tests like we identify CO2 by passing it through lime water and that oxygen rekindles a burning flame but all I have come across for Nitrogen is that it extinguishes a burning splint, which I think a lot of gases should be able to do so is there any other way to identify Nitrogen

There's no such simple way. Probably measuring density would be easiest, if it was pure enough.

Nitrogen is an inert gas, so you can use litmus paper. Any change in litmus paper indicates acidic/basic gas but for nitrogen, there won't be any change. Alternatively, there is an instrument called katharometer. See: https://www.sciencing.com/test-nitrogen-gas-5387177/

An easy way to identify nitrogen gas is by its emission spectrum. This was first done by Robert Strutt, AKA Lord Rayleigh, in 1910:

[A]n electrical discharge in nitrogen gas produced "active nitrogen"... [a] "whirling cloud of brilliant yellow light".

Of course, that can help identify virtually any chemical, and is not specific to nitrogen. On occasion, I'd demonstrate the colors emitted by ordinary clear incandescent lamps when placed on a high-voltage coil. Some are filled with argon, some $\ce{Ar-N2}$ mixes, and some older lamps are in vacuo. [One can make an X-ray machine with an evacuated lamp and high-voltage DC supply, but there's no visible spectrum.]
Continuing with this electrical theme, consider that the inert oops.. noble sorry "Group 18"* gases were first isolated by Henry Cavendish, using an electric discharge to force all other chemicals in air to react. The products were dissolved in water and "potash", $\ce{KOH}$, forming potassium nitrate, $\ce{KNO3}$. You can perform a similar demonstration for historical purposes, testing for $\ce{KNO3}$, though this is not an efficient test for nitrogen.
Note that commercial $\ce{N2}$ analyzers may actually be $\ce{O2}$ analyzers, finding nitrogen leaks by the absence of oxygen, since it is not so easy to get a rapid, accurate, quantitative analysis for nitrogen, since $\ce{N2}$ is not easily reactive and does not have an infrared absorption spectrum.
One could use an electric discharge to convert $\ce{N2}$ to its various oxides (NOx), and use an electrochemical sensor such as the MiCS-2714 to detect those products.
* Since first Xe, then Kr and other (relatively) stable compounds have been made, this group is no longer considered as inert or noble.
Sic transit gloria mundi... and now Pluto is no longer a planet, too.

Totally agree on your last note: Xenon trioxide is one of the most unstable and explosive compound which can rip out oxygen from water.  Not so "noble" of xenon trioxide to do that ;)

Nitrogen $\ce{N2}$ can be recognized by passing it in a heated tube containing magnesium, once oxygen has been removed. Hot magnesium $\ce{Mg}$ reacts with nitrogen $\ce{N2}$  to produce solid magnesium nitride according to $$\ce{4 Mg + 3 N2 -> 2 Mg2N3}$$ Surprisingly enough, this reaction was used for prooving the existence of rare gases. Cavendish in $1785$, then Rayleigh in $1804$ were rather surprised to see that it is not possible to fix all constituants of air by magnesium. When sending an air current through a long hot tube filled with metallic magnesium, oxygen reacts first to produce magnesium oxide, then nitrogen reacts to produce magnesium nitride. But whatever the length of the tube filled with magnesium metal, it was impossible to have $100$% of the air transformed into a solid magnesium compound. The $1$% remaining was of course not nitrogen, but argon. This was new, and this was a proof that air contains a new gaseous element with valence zero : argon.
To go back to Abhinav Krishna's question, it could be mentioned that the easyest way for identifying nitrogen $\ce{N2}$ is probably the reaction with hot magnesium, once oxygen $\ce{O2}$ has been eliminated.

Nitrogen pretty much reacts with most metals, so this seems to be a suitable test (although some requires pure nitrogen). Magnesium happens to be little bit on the cheaper and affordable side :)

Little bit of history in the magnesium nitride test if you are interested :)
